# Creating a Mockup REST API

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, rest

I'm currently trying to create a NodeJS server or something similar to mockup a REST API that reads in a JSON file and responds to requests with that data. I really only need GET requests supported. What is the best way to go about this?

Here's what I have so far:

```
/**
 * Sample items REST API
 */
function ItemsRepository() {
    this.items = [];
}

ItemsRepository.prototype.find = function (id) {
    var item = this.items.filter(function(item) {
        return item.itemId == id;
    })[0];
    if (null == item) {
        throw new Error('item not found');
    }
    return item;
}

/**
 * Retrieve all items
 * items: array of items
 */
ItemsRepository.prototype.findAll = function () {
    return this.items;
}

/**
 * API
 */
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var itemRepository = new ItemsRepository();
app.configure(function () {
    // used to parse JSON object given in the body request
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
});
/**
 * HTTP GET /items
 * items: the list of items in JSON format
 */
app.get('/items', function (request, response) {
    response.json({items: itemRepository.findAll()});
});
/**
 * HTTP GET /items/:id
 * Param: :id is the unique identifier of the item you want to retrieve
 * items: the item with the specified :id in a JSON format
 * Error: 404 HTTP code if the item doesn't exists
 */
app.get('/items/:id', function (request, response) {
    var itemId = request.params.id;
    try {
        response.json(itemRepository.find(itemId));
    } catch (exception) {
        response.send(404);
    }

});


app.listen(8080); //to port on which the express server listen
```

I know that I would use the following to include the file, I just don't know how to stuff the data into Items.

```
var responseItemsData = require('./items-list.json');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is trivial in node. You can load the data by requiring the `.json` file directly

```
var responseData = require('./my-json-file'); //.json extension optional
//Do this during your startup code, not during the request handler
```

Then to send it:

```
res.write(JSON.stringify(responseData));
```

The rest of the code you need is easily available in almost every node.js tutorial on the web.

Comment: So how would I only return some of the data in a request like '/items/:id' as shown in my code above?

Comment: Your code above looks like it should work. You're bypassing the whole async part of node, which is a huge part of knowing what you are doing, as well as using callbacks with errors instead of exceptions, but for synchronous code, your snippet above is at least coherent.

Comment: How would I populate my Items with the contents of the file I read in with 
var responseData = require('./my-json-file') ?

Comment: function ItemsRepository() {
    this.items = require('./my-items-json-file');
}

Comment: Do I need to wrap my JSON in anything or can it be raw? I'm getting all kind of syntax errors and I don't think my JSON is incorrect.

Comment: stackoverflow really discourages this kind of back and forth remote debugging. Try IRC or pair programming or post a separate question with the details we need to help you. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jasmine+sinon:

```
var Episode = Backbone.Model.extend({
      url: function() {
        return "/episode/" + this.id;
      }
});

  beforeEach(function() {
    this.server = sinon.fakeServer.create();
  });

  afterEach(function() {
    this.server.restore();
  });

  it("should fire the change event", function() {
    var callback = sinon.spy();

    this.server.respondWith("GET", "/episode/123",
      [200, {"Content-Type": "application/json"},'{"id":123,"title":"Hollywood - Part 2"}']);

    var episode = new Episode({id: 123});

    // Bind to the change event on the model
    episode.bind('change', callback);

    // makes an ajax request to the server
    episode.fetch(); 

    // Fake server responds to the request
    this.server.respond(); 

    // Expect that the spy was called with the new model
    expect(callback.called).toBeTruthy();
    expect(callback.getCall(0).args[0].attributes)
      .toEqual({id: 123,
                title: "Hollywood - Part 2"});

  });
```

more details in: https://github.com/cld-santos/simplologia/tree/master/javascript-lessons/src/test/javascript/Sinon

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to simply use the static middleware.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use('/api', express.static(__dirname + '/data'));
app.use('.*', express.static(__dirname + '/assets'));
```

This assumes that you are eventually going to put the REST api at /api but that while you're testing your data is going to be in the `data` directory and that your CSS/JS/HTML is in the assets folder. In reality you can put it whereever you want, but you now can put all your dev json separate from your code.

Answer (score 0):

I created a tool for this purpose
https://github.com/homerquan/kakuen